# How to redirect to deshboard page after login successfull

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router

I am working on django rest api and react js.

I connected successfully api with react js frontend. I can loggin successfully but i am not able to redirect the to deshboard page.

I want to connect /deshboard/overview/ after login.

I also tried with BrowserRouter, Route but facing error.

index.js

```
// =========================================================
// * Volt React Dashboard
// =========================================================

// * Product Page: https://themesberg.com/product/dashboard/volt-react
// * Copyright 2021 Themesberg (https://www.themesberg.com)
// * Official Repository: https://github.com/themesberg/volt-react-dashboard
// * License: MIT License (https://themesberg.com/licensing)

// * Designed and coded by https://themesberg.com

// =========================================================

// * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software. Please contact us to request a removal.

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { HashRouter, BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Router } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

// core styles
import "./scss/volt.scss";

import Auth, { useAuthActions } from 'use-eazy-auth'
import { AuthRoute, GuestRoute } from 'use-eazy-auth/routes'

// vendor styles
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";
import "react-datetime/css/react-datetime.css";

import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage";
import DashboardOverview from "./pages/dashboard/DashboardOverview"
import LoginPage from "./pages/examples/Signin";
import ScrollToTop from "./components/ScrollToTop";

import { Component } from "react"
import { Routes } from './routes';

class App extends Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      viewCompleted: false,
      activeItem: {
        title: "",
        description: "",
        completed: false
      },
      todoList: []
      };
  }
    

    handleSubmit = item => {
      this.toggle();
      alert();
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:8000/colorcast_app/login/")
      if (item.id) {
        axios
          .put(`http://localhost:8000/colorcast_app/login/`, item)
        return;  
      }
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:8000/colorcast_app/login/", item)
    };
    renderItems = () => {
      const { viewCompleted } = this.state;
      const newItems = this.state.todoList.filter(
        item => item.completed === viewCompleted
      );
      return newItems.map(item => (
        <li 
          key={item.id}
          className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"
        >
          <span 
            className={`todo-title mr-2 ${
              this.state.viewCompleted ? "completed-todo" : ""
            }`}
            title={item.description}
            >
              {item.title}
            </span>
        </li>
      ));
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <main className="content">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-10 mx-auto p-0">
            <div className="card p-3">
              <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
                {this.renderItems()}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
      )
    }
  }
  
export default App;

ReactDOM.render(
  <HashRouter>
    <ScrollToTop />
    {/* <HomePage /> */}
    {/* <DashboardOverview /> */}
    < LoginPage />
  </HashRouter>,

  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

routes.js

```
export const Routes = {
    // pages
    Presentation: { path: "/" },
    DashboardOverview: { path: "/dashboard/overview" },
    Transactions: { path: "/transactions" },
    Settings: { path: "/settings" },
    Upgrade: { path: "/upgrade" },
    BootstrapTables: { path: "/tables/bootstrap-tables" },
    Billing: { path: "/examples/billing" },
    Invoice: { path: "/examples/invoice" },
    Signin: { path: "/examples/sign-in" },
    Signup: { path: "/examples/sign-up" },
    ForgotPassword: { path: "/examples/forgot-password" },
    ResetPassword: { path: "/examples/reset-password" },
    Lock: { path: "/examples/lock" },
    NotFound: { path: "/examples/404" },
    ServerError: { path: "/examples/500" },

    // docs
    DocsOverview: { path: "/documentation/overview" },
    DocsDownload: { path: "/documentation/download" },
    DocsQuickStart: { path: "/documentation/quick-start" },
    DocsLicense: { path: "/documentation/license" },
    DocsFolderStructure: { path: "/documentation/folder-structure" },
    DocsBuild: { path: "/documentation/build-tools" },
    DocsChangelog: { path: "/documentation/changelog" },

    // components
    Accordions: { path: "/components/accordions" },
    Alerts: { path: "/components/alerts" },
    Badges: { path: "/components/badges" },
    Widgets: { path: "/widgets" },
    Breadcrumbs: { path: "/components/breadcrumbs" },
    Buttons: { path: "/components/buttons" },
    Forms: { path: "/components/forms" },
    Modals: { path: "/components/modals" },
    Navs: { path: "/components/navs" },
    Navbars: { path: "/components/navbars" },
    Pagination: { path: "/components/pagination" },
    Popovers: { path: "/components/popovers" },
    Progress: { path: "/components/progress" },
    Tables: { path: "/components/tables" },
    Tabs: { path: "/components/tabs" },
    Tooltips: { path: "/components/tooltips" },
    Toasts: { path: "/components/toasts" },
    WidgetsComponent: { path: "/components/widgets" }
};
```

Signin.js

```
import React from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faAngleLeft, faEnvelope, faUnlockAlt } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { faFacebookF, faGithub, faTwitter } from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";
import { Col, Row, Form, Card, Button, FormCheck, Container, InputGroup } from '@themesberg/react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router'
import { useAuthActions, useAuthState } from 'use-eazy-auth'

import HomePage from "../../pages/HomePage"

import { Routes } from "../../routes";
import BgImage from "../../assets/img/illustrations/signin.svg";

import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";

// function loginAPI(email, password){
//   // axios
//   //   .post("http://localhost:8000/colorcast_app/login/")

  

//   axios.post('http://localhost:8000/colorcast_app/login/', {
//   }, {
//       headers: {
//           'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
//       }
//   })
//   .then(response => { 
//     console.log(response)
//   })
//   .catch(error => {
//       console.log(error.response)
//   });

//   alert(email, password)

//   // const response = await axios({
//   //   method: 'post',
//   //   url: 'http://localhost:8000/colorcast_app/login',
//   //   data: form,
//   //   headers: {
//   //       'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form._boundary}`,
//   //   },
//   // });

//   // fetch('http://localhost:8000/colorcast_app/login/', {
//   //   method: 'POST',
//   //   headers: {
//   //     'Accept': 'application/json',
//   //     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
//   //   },
//   //   body: JSON.stringify({
//   //     user: username,
//   //     pass: password,
//   //   })
//   // })
// }


export default () => {

  // // const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
  // const [username, setUsername] = useState("")
  // const [password, setPassword] = useState("")

  // const history = useHistory();

  // // console.log(email, password)

  // const loginAPI = async () => {
  //   let formField = new FormData()

  //   // formField.append('email', email)
  //   formField.append('username', username)
  //   formField.append('password', password)

  //   console.log(username)

  //   // await axios({
  //   //   method: 'post',
  //   //   url: 'http://localhost:8000/colorcast_app/login/',
  //   //   data: FormData
  //   // }).then((response) => {
  //   //   console.log(response.data)
  //   //   history.push('/register/')
  //   // })

  //   axios.post('http://localhost:8000/colorcast_app/login/', {
  //   }, {
  //       headers: {
  //           'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
  //       }
  //   })
  //   .then(response => { 
  //     console.log(response)
  //   })
  //   .catch(error => {
  //       console.log(error.response)
  //   });

  // }

  let history = useHistory();
  const [username, setUsername] = useState(null)
  const [password, setPassword] = useState(null)

  const loginAPI = async () => {
      let formField = new FormData()
      formField.append('username',username)
      formField.append('password',password)

      await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url:'http://localhost:8000/colorcast_app/login/',
        data: formField
      }).then(response=>{
        console.log(response.data);
        // history.push('/dashboard/overview')
        // history.push(Routes.Presentation.path)
      })
  }
   

  return (
    <main>
      <section className="d-flex align-items-center my-5 mt-lg-6 mb-lg-5">
        <Container>
          <p className="text-center">
            <Card.Link as={Link} to={Routes.DashboardOverview.path} className="text-gray-700">
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleLeft} className="me-2" /> Back to homepage
            </Card.Link>
          </p>
          <Row className="justify-content-center form-bg-image" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${BgImage})` }}>
            <Col xs={12} className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
              <div className="bg-white shadow-soft border rounded border-light p-4 p-lg-5 w-100 fmxw-500">
                <div className="text-center text-md-center mb-4 mt-md-0">
                  <h3 className="mb-0">Sign in to our platform</h3>
                </div>
                <Form className="mt-4" onSubmit={() => loginAPI()}>
                {/* <Form className="mt-4" > */}
                  {/* <Form.Group id="email" className="mb-4">
                    <Form.Label>Your Email</Form.Label>
                    <InputGroup>
                      <InputGroup.Text>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEnvelope} />
                      </InputGroup.Text>
                      <Form.Control autoFocus required type="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} placeholder="example@company.com" />
                    </InputGroup>
                  </Form.Group> */}
                  <Form.Group id="username" className="mb-4">
                    <Form.Label>Your Username</Form.Label>
                    <InputGroup>
                      <InputGroup.Text>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEnvelope} />
                      </InputGroup.Text>
                      <Form.Control autoFocus required type="username" value={username} onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)} placeholder="example" />
                    </InputGroup>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group id="password" className="mb-4">
                      <Form.Label>Your Password</Form.Label>
                      <InputGroup>
                        <InputGroup.Text>
                          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUnlockAlt} />
                        </InputGroup.Text>
                        <Form.Control required type="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} placeholder="Password" />
                      </InputGroup>
                    </Form.Group>
                    <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-4">
                      <Card.Link className="small text-end">Lost password?</Card.Link>
                    </div>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Button variant="primary" type="submit" className="w-100">
                    Sign in
                  </Button>
                </Form>

                <div className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mt-4">
                  <span className="fw-normal">
                    Not registered?
                    <Card.Link as={Link} to={Routes.Signup.path} className="fw-bold">
                      {` Create account `}
                    </Card.Link>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </section>
    </main>
  );
};
```

Comment: What error you are facing. Please post it as well

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to use functional components with React you can find the full docs on https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html.

To redirect with a class component use

```
this.props.history.push('/path')
```

or

With Hooks and functional components you can use the `useHistory` hook like this

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
```

Then assign the hook to a const

```
const history = useHistory();
```

Then in your event add this line of code to the route you want

```
history.push("/home");
```